# Azure API Management SOAP to REST Policy Editor Issues

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an interesting problem with Azure API Management policies. I need to iterate a JSON array from my front-end. I am creating an XML input packet to send to my backend service based on my input JSON.

The problem I am facing is the policy editor seems to be mangling my policy when it saves. Any code written inside of my {for} loop is removed and placed outside of the loop, leaving whitespace in my for loop code. I am using the liquid template in my set-body tag

Here is what I am trying to save...

```
                            {% for item in body.code.mycodes %}
                            <Lookup>
                                <Identifier>{{item.identifier}}</Identifier>
                            </Lookup>
                            {% endfor %}
```

But after I save my policy and re-open it, this is what it has done.

```
                            <Lookup>
                                <Identifier>{{item.identifier}}</Identifier>
                            </Lookup>
                            {% for item in body.code.mycodes %}

                            {% endfor %}
```

I don't know if this is a bug or I'm doing something completely incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. We are working to resolve it.  For the moment, the old publisher portal is the workaround.